Unable to use basic auth for Twiml request url
I am trying to setup a TwiML app that uses basic auth in the request. I am setting the Request URL like : https://user:password@myurl.com/bot-handling/start-call.
Unfortunately I cannot get this to work and my fast api server is returning a 401 error.
However, I can hit my server and get an appropriate response with this curl command:
curl -X POST   -u auser:apassword   https://myurl.com/bot-handling/start-call
What am I missing here? The docs describe using basic auth here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#http-authentication .
